# Form validation before AJAX request to submit a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to validate a form before it submitted with ajax. I wrote the code below but I get a message: "Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined" in chrome JS console. The message refer to line 25, where the form.validate function is defined. Any suggestion how to fix it?

Here is the form header:

```
            <form id="contactForm" name="contactForm">
```

Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = document.querySelector("#contactForm");

    $("#submitButton").click(function() {
        if(form_validate()) {
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url: 'contact.php',
                data: $('#contactForm').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});


/*
 * @return {boolean}
 */
    form_validate = function () {

        var name = document.forms["contactForm"]["user-name"].value;
        var email = document.forms["contactForm"]["email"].value;
        var phone = document.forms["contactForm"]["phone"].value;
        var message = document.forms["contactForm"]["message"].value;

        var validationAlert = document.getElementById("formValidationAlerts");
        var letterOnlyRegExp = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;
        var emailRegExp = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

        // Check if the fields full name, E-mail and message are filled.
        if ((name == null || name == "") ||
            (email == null || email == "") ||
            (message == null || message == "")) {
            validationAlert.innerHTML = "* Your Full Name, Your E-mail Address and Your Message are Required fields." +
                " Please fill all of them.";
            return false;
        }

        // Check if the full name is valid (English letters only).
        if (!(name.match(letterOnlyRegExp))) {
            validationAlert.innerHTML = "* Please Enter a Valid Name (English letters only).";
            return false;
        }

        // Check if the E-mail is valid.
        if (!(email.match(emailRegExp))) {
            validationAlert.innerHTML = "* Please Enter a Valid E-mail.";
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    };
```

**EDIT: I uploaded the updated code. Now the validation works fine, but I got this errors after form submitted (the errors come from the PHP file).**

Notice: Undefined index: user-name in /home/web/public_html/contact.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: email in /home/web/public_html/contact.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: phone in /home/web/public_html/contact.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: company in /home/web/public_html/contact.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: message in /home/web/public_html/contact.php on line 11

here is the PHP file:

```
<?php

        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set("display_errors", "On");

        $subject="Message from Web";
        $sender=$_POST["user-name"];
        $senderEmail=$_POST["email"];
        $senderPhone=$_POST["phone"];
        $senderCompany=$_POST["company"];
        $message=$_POST["message"];

        $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\nPhone: $senderPhone\nCompany: $senderCompany\n\n$message";

        mail('mymail@gmail.com', $mailBody, $sender);

        echo "Thank you! we will contact you soon.";

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to rename form.validate to form_validate and this should fix your error. Also you should consider to remove method="post" from form headers since you are sending it through AJAX (using GET also!!)

Comment: Thanks, I did these two changes. Now the validation works but if it succeed the AJAX call not works correctly. I don't see the content of the "contact.php" file in the #result div as expected. Do you know how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: of course. here is my php (it works before).
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", "On");

    $subject="Message from Web";
    $sender=$_POST["user-name"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["email"];
    $senderPhone=$_POST["phone"];
    $senderCompany=$_POST["company"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];

    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\nPhone: $senderPhone\nCompany: $senderCompany\n\n$message";

    mail('mymail@gmail.com', $mailBody, $sender);

    echo "Thank you! we will contact you soon.";

?>

Comment: Ok. put $('#contactForm').serialize() instead of form.serialize() and remove the form.submit();

Comment: BTW did you change if(form.validate()) { to if(form_validate()) { ?? Please update your question with the new code

Comment: Thanks Lelio Faieta. I changed if(form.validate()) { to if(form_validate()). Now I get the PHP result at the #result div as expected but it seems like the form fields are sent empty - without any value inside (please look at my original message, I uploaded the errors I got from the PHP file). Any suggestion? Appriciate your help.

Comment: looks like all the input field have not a name property with the same value as the id. you shoul have something like: <input id="user-name" name="user-name"> since jquery is using the id and get and post use the name

Comment: I have just checked it and all the filed have the same name as the id. When I clicked on submit I still received this PHP errors and an E-mail with empty values. There is other cause to this issue? Thanks Lelio.

Comment: Can I suggest you to: close this question as solved, open a new question posting ALL your html and javascript code with the form?? This is getting off-topic

Comment: Ok, I'll do it. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway... you should use $_GET['user-name'] since you are sending data to the form using GET. Or you can change type:'GET' to type: 'POST'

Comment: Thanks you very much, it solved the problem!! 
Very appreciate your BIG help :)

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the local form variable in this line:

```
var form = document.querySelector("#contactForm");
```

is overriding your global form object for which the form.validate method is stored in.

Try changing this line:

```
if(form.validate()) {
```

to:

```
if(window.form.validate()) {
```

Comment: Thanks Mex. I did what Lelio Faieta said and now the validation works fine but I have another issue with the AJAX call. I wrote it above, hope you can help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems strange that you're calling form.submit() after the form has already been uploaded via AJAX.  Also are you 100% sure that you're form_validate function is returning true?

Comment: Ok, I deleted form.submit() line. It seems like after submit the page loads again (which should not happen when using AJAX). I'm sure that form_validate function returning true, I tested it a lot before. I really not know how to fix this annoying issue.